# Use css variable in nth-child(3n + 3) instead of 3

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-variables

i'm trying to use a CSS variable in a nth-child() selector, im using `li:nth-child(3n+3)` to give every third `<li>` a certain style.

this topic turned out to be very hard to google, i could not find any result for my use case.

currently my code looks roughly like this:

```
li {
  width: 25%;
  margin-right: 12.5%;
}
li:nth-child(3n+3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

i want to refactor my code so it can be easily changed, but i can't figure out how to use CSS variables in the :nth-child(3n+3) selector. i want to achieve something like this:

```
:root {
  --number: 3;
}
li {
  width: calc(100% / (var(--number) + 1));
  margin-right: calc((100% / (var(--number) + 1)) / (var(--number) - 1));
}
li:nth-child(var(--number)n + var(--number)) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

sadly, the `:nth-child(✖n + ✖)` does not work as expected when using vars instead of numbers. my goal is to adjust the whole style with the one `--number` variable.

i created a codepen example:
https://codepen.io/hergi/pen/xxRrmGv

any ideas/keywords or sources to help me solve this issue are highly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: you cannot, use SASS for this

Answer (score -2):

**I think you want something like this..**
You just need to use **`nth-of-type(3n+3)`**

You can't use Cascading `variables` in `selectors`.. for more detail visit this
[Is it possible to use CSS vars in CSS3 selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951877/is-it-possible-to-use-css-vars-in-css3-selectors)

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 25%;
  margin-right: 12.5%;
}

li:nth-of-type(3n+3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

li:nth-of-type(3n+3) button {
  background: #0095ff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><button>Button</button></li>
  <li><button>Button</button></li>
  <li><button>Button</button></li>
  <li><button>Button</button></li>
  <li><button>Button</button></li>
  <li><button>Button</button></li>
  <li><button>Button</button></li>
  <li><button>Button</button></li>
  <li><button>Button</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that is not what i am trying to achieve, my goal is to be able to  use a variable in my nth-selector instead of a fixed number. i was able to find a solution via JS, since these css nth-selectors dont seem to support variables