# Pass data variable as argument in style section of vue2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vuejs2, vuetify.js

let's we have a data variable and i want to use this data variable for my style.

```
data() 
{
 return{
        selected:{
         index: 2
        }
     }
}
<style>
.parent-table >>> .table-row:nth-child(/* here i want to pass selected.index */) {
   background: red;
}
</style>
```

My use case is that i have a table component used in my landing page . I want to change background of selected row of table from my landing page.

Comment: I think you should make a method that applies a css property with the index with `this.selected.index`. You have various class name `.parent-table` and `.table-row`, I don't realy understand, but you can apply css property with the css selector `:nth-child(index)`

Comment: @RyukShi actually, .table-row is the class of the table component's row and I want to override their nth-child(index)

Comment: ok ok I had this idea, that might look like this, in the method : `document.querySelector('css_selector').style.backgroundColor('red');`

Comment: @RyukShi I have already tried this one but it's not working.

Comment: @NileshMishra Can you please confirm, are you creating HTML table or vuetify `v-data-table` ? Also, do you want to change the row color on click on the row ?

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I have a component Table which is created using both HTML and vuetify v-data-table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think we have any solution as per your requirement in `Vue 2`. In `Vue 3.2`, They introduced this feature which enables component state-driven dynamic CSS values in `<style>` tags. You can read that out [`here`](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3.2.html).

After understand your exact requirement and post spending few hours on this requirement, Here I am coming up with the solution in JavaScript way as we can't use dynamic variables in CSS `nth-child` selectors. You can have a look in this SO post : [`Is it possible to use CSS vars in CSS3 selectors?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951877/is-it-possible-to-use-css-vars-in-css3-selectors)

Looks like you have to do update the style of `nth-child` in pure JS way.

Working Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: {
      index: 2
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let listSelector = document.querySelector(`li:nth-child(${this.selected.index})`);
    listSelector.style.backgroundColor = 'lightGreen';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li>First list item</li>
    <li>Second list item</li>
    <li>Third list item</li>
    <li>Fourth list item</li>
    <li>Fifth list item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't change the component I have to do something in the parent vue file without disturbing Table.vue file.

Comment: @NileshMishra I understood your requirement now. I don't think we can pass vue variables into a `<styles>` tag as it is static. But we can find some way to achieve this by using CSS variables .. I need to spend some more time on this requirement you have. Will hopefully update you by tomorrow EOD.

Comment: @NileshMishra I updated the answer as per your requirement. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: I have already tried this one,but it's not working.

Comment: But it's working in the above code snippet. So it should work locally as well .. did you tried with `/deep/` css selector ?

Comment: I recommend the solution below using CSS vars into your script/template tags.

Comment: @kissu By that way we can pass the dynamic variables as a value but author wants to access dynamic variable in the selector which is not possible directly by using Vue 2.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how to explain it. but here's how to pass `variables` to `style scope`

`PROPS`:

```
props: {
    bgColor: {
       type: String,
       default: "#ff0000" //RED
   }
 },
```

`COMPUTED` (variables that can be used as arguments):

```
computed: {
    tableRowColor() {
      return {
        '--bg-color': this.bgColor,
        '--index': this.selected.index //from your data
      }
   }
}
```

Example of accessing the `variables` inside `style scoped`:

```
<style scoped>

     table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid;
     }

     table {
        width: 100%;
        background: var(--bg-color); /*here is how to access the variable */
    }
</style>
```

note: You don't need to make the props if you only want to get the `index` from your `data`

Comment: I have to pass dynamic parameter in nth-child()

Comment: This is indeed the way to go in Vue2.

Comment: @kissu This is not what author wants. By this way we can pass the dynamic variables as a value but author wants to access dynamic variable in the selector which is not possible directly by using Vue 2.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal for me, it achieves the same goal even if not exactly written the way OP expected. But yeah, maybe it's different.

Comment: @kissu It will not achieve the same goal my friend. where that `--index` variable is using in his answer ? Can you pass dynamic values as a selector ?  You can not pass dynamic value in `:nth-child` directly just using CSS. I did lot of research and then at the end I came up with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

> this is how you pass a data property to a css property.

```html
<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            color: 'red',
        }),
    };
</script>
<style scoped>
.card-text-color {
    color: v-bind(color)
}
```

Comment: This is not available in Vue2.