# CSS color-scheme selector or media query

Tags: css, media-queries, color-scheme

Is it possible to write a media query or a CSS selector that would only apply when `color-scheme` is dark.

```css
:root { 
    /*Special CSS variable see: https://twitter.com/diegohaz/status/1529543787311144961*/
    color-scheme: dark;
}

:root {
  --blue-france: #f5f5fe;
}

/* Psudo code, I know it isn't possible to use var in selectors, I just hope there is a way around it in this perticulat usecase. */
:root:where(var(color-scheme)="dark") {
  /* Overwrite default value */
  --blue-france: #1b1b35;
}

/* Alternative psudo code, it works with prefers-color-scheme but not with color-scheme */
@media screen and (color-scheme: dark) {
    :root {
       --blue-france: #1b1b35;
    }
}
```

I'm open to alternative solutions as long as it doesn't involve JavaScript or setting attributes on the `<head />` or `<body />`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use CSS vars in CSS3 selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951877/is-it-possible-to-use-css-vars-in-css3-selectors)

Comment: @ATP Thank you for your suggestion, it tells me that no, it isn't possible, at least with selectors but I'm hoping for a suggestion in this very specific use case.

Comment: I don't get what you want. If you mark a selector with `color-scheme: dark`, then what's the point of checking it? You already know its `dark` and you can just add more styles?

Comment: I think you're looking for [`@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)`](https://css-tricks.com/dark-modes-with-css/)

Comment: @caTS `<style> :root { color-scheme: dark; } </style>` is happened dynamically via SSR in the head.  
The rest of the CSS is static.
Sometime the value is 'dark', sometime it's 'light' it depends of the user preference, it's not hard coded.

Comment: @JamesLong thanks you for your suggestion but unfortunately `prefers-color-scheme` is the OS prefered scheme, not the one currently enabled via `:root { color-scheme: dark; }`...

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you are looking for a dark mode without Javascript? Here is this code snippet [based on this snippet](https://codepen.io/rafaelsnts/pen/BEzZoX) for Dark Mode WITHOUT Javascript, just pure CSS.

```css
/**
 * VARIABLES
 */

:root {
  --bg: #f8fafc;
  --panel-bg: #FFFFFF;
  --panel-border: #CCCCCC;
  --panel-title: #343f44;
  --panel-text: #54666d;
  --btn: #3eb0ef;
}


/**
 * GENERIC STYLES 
 */

body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}


/**
 * TOGGLERS 
 */

#toggleMode {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.toggleDark,
.toggleLight {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.toggleDark {
  display: block;
  color: #222;
}

.toggleDark:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.toggleLight {
  display: none;
  color: white;
}

#toggleMode:checked~.toggleDark {
  display: none;
}

#toggleMode:checked~.toggleLight {
  display: block;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--bg);
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 50px 20px;
}

#toggleMode:checked~#container {
  --bg: #020202;
  --panel-bg: #111413;
  --panel-border: #1f2322;
  --panel-title: #8e9294;
  --panel-text: #505456;
  --btn: #2962fe;
  background-color: var(--bg);
}


/**
 * PANEL 
 */

.panel {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.panel .content h2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: var(--panel-title);
}

.panel .content p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: var(--panel-text);
}

.panel .content button {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: var(--btn);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.panel .content button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggleMode">
  <label for="toggleMode" class="toggleDark">Dark Mode</label>
  <label for="toggleMode" class="toggleLight">Light Mode</label>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>This is a title</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ullamcorper erat quis faucibus pulvinar. Duis vel ex non sem ultricies consectetur. Donec blandit dolor ac libero euismod, sit amet blandit libero scelerisque.</p>
        <button>Read more</button>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet, it's interesting. I played with it for a while but unfortunately I can't make it work in my usecase.

Comment: This is a giant copy paste generic example that has a lot of complexity that doesn't answer the question.