# media query or way to check which color scheme is active on element level

Tags: css

I know there is a `prefers-color-scheme`, e.g.:

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    ...
}
```

But this is not suitable for my implementation because `prefers-color-scheme` checks the OS  theme choice.

In my design some element may be light theme, and other elements dark theme, on the same page. Additionally the user can select a different theme in the website, that is different to their OS theme.

So I would like to know the state a elements CSS `color-scheme` property. Yes I could assign a custom property say `--color-scheme: light` to every element, but that is duplicating functionality.

The reason I don't do the following is because most of the styling is in web components, and this will not style shadow DOMs:

```css
.light { --color-scheme: light; }
.dark { --color-scheme: dark; }
:host { color-scheme: var(--color-scheme); }
```

Is there a way to detect if the current elements `color-scheme` is light or dark, and adjust the colors accordingly, e.g.

```css
/* Wishful code that does not work*/
@media (color-scheme: light) {
   --fg: black;
}
@media (color-scheme: dark) {
   --fg: white;
}
```

NOTE: My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73841094/css-color-scheme-selector-or-media-query) which has no solution, so maybe its not possible.

Comment: I was looking for a similar feature. I found a proposal in [CSS Working Group drafts](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7561) that would allow it in the future (so apparently, it is not possible at the moment...).

Comment: Thanks that is great, and I see `light-dark` has been approved. However it's not even listed on caniuse.com yet, but the future is bright! ... or dark, it's however you want it, yay!